# cannot get the right output of a recursive function

Tags: c++, g++

what did I do wrong in this functions. I am pretty sure the problem is at `base = exp(base, pwr /= 2) * exp(base, pwr /= 2);` but I cannot think of a logical reason. is there a possible way to write a parameter like that? thanks in advance. (p.s my output of this function is a `2` which is wrong)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

unsigned long& exp(unsigned long& base, unsigned long& pwr)
{
    if(pwr == 0)
      base = 1;
    else if(pwr == 1)
      base = base;
    else
      base = exp(base, pwr /= 2) * exp(base, pwr /= 2);
    return base;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long n=2, m = 4;
    cout << exp(n,m) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this in a debugger?

Comment: What is the function supposed to do and what is expected output?

Comment: Because you're using references everywhere, every manipulation you make to `base` or `pwr` affects all the current calls to the function. Remove all the references in your code and try again; if it still doesn't work at least it will be about 100x easier to debug.

Comment: You are right, your algorithm is plain wrong, but it feels like homework, so giving out the answer doesn't seem right. You should step through the code with a debugger or `printf` the value of base with each iteration to better understand what your code is doing. (And maybe go back to the drawing board to figure out what the correct code is)

Comment: Think a little more about how you divide your problem into subproblems

Comment: @madd0 it's not a homework . I am just testing how reference works in different places. ( I have the fundamental concepts ), just wondering that if reference is a lvalue, why this expression wouldn't work. (if I change the codes to `else {pwr /= 2; base = exp(base, pwr) * exp(base, pwr);}` it works. I am trying to put them together. but I don't see anything wrong with the expression.

Comment: Function arguments are evaluated in unspecified order at the call site, so you may want to think about what happens during the recursive call.

Comment: The change you mention works because you're only dividing `pwr` by 2 once per round; in the above example, you're dividing twice. Because pwr is passed-by-ref, `/=` affects every instance of `pwr`. Handling variables by reference means all instances of `pwr` point to the same location in memory. Any assignment operation will be reflected in all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are five things to note about this line:

```
  base = exp(base, pwr /= 2) * exp(base, pwr /= 2);
```

1. As noted in a comment above, `base` is passed by reference, not value, so there is only one copy of it and you're changing its value.  This is a bad idea.
2. `pwr` is also passed by reference and you're changing its value when you use `/=` instead of just `/`.  There are two `/=` statements in this line, so after this line runs, `pwr` now has one fourth its original value.
3. The exp function will get run twice each time you run this line.  It would make more sense to store the value and then square it.
4. `/2` is integer division, so it will round down.  So if you give it a number like 3 as an exponent, it will not work correctly because 3/2 is 1.  If you correct the other mistakes and the call it with an exponent of 7, it will end up only doing `exp(2,7) = exp(2,3)*exp(2,3) = exp(2,1)*exp(2,1)*exp(2,1)*exp(2,1) = 16` when obviously the correct answer is 128.  This function, as designed, will only work correctly when the exponent is a power of 2.
5. Good thing that number 4 is true because if you did get exp(2,1.5) you'd never terminate since it wouldn't match your base cases.  You should probably rethink your algorithm generally.

Comment: 6. Assigning a variable twice within the same line. Your `/=`ing pwr by 2 twice, which might work, or cause a large variety of bugs.

Comment: That was actually part of the point of 2.  I noted that it was being a fourth of its original value.  I'll edit it to make it more clear, though.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem that I can see is that you pass `base` and `pwr` by reference.
When you do this, their global value gets modified every time yo call `exp`,  so the output you are getting should be expected based on the code you wrote.

To get a correct result I would replace

```
exp(base, pwr /= 2) * exp(base, pwr /= 2);
```

with

```
exp(base, pwr/2) * exp(base, pwr/2);
```

because your `exp(2, 4) = exp(2, 2) * exp(2, 1)` is not really correct..

Comment: also as pepsi says, this won't work with exponents not being a power of 2...

Answer (score 1):

Since you claim this isn't homework:

1. As others have mentioned, the references don't belong here. Each recursive call needs the values for that particular point in the calculation.
2. `exp(base, pwr /= 2) * exp(base, pwr /= 2);`

   This won't work as expected when your exponent is not a multiple of 2. After you fix the reference thing, if you still really want to do it this way, try:

   `exp(base, pwr/2) * exp(base, (pwr/2 + pwr%2));`

Comment: I am still thinking. I understand that it doesn't work if it's not a multiple of 2.

Answer (score 1):

We can step through this fairly easily, the first time through exp base is 2 and pwr is 4 so we call with exp (2, 1) * exp (2, 0) (remember you are setting pwr = pwr / 2).  So the first one evaluates to 2 and the second evaluates to 1 so you are returning the result of 2 * 1 which is 2.  I think you're code means to return the result of exp (2, 1) * exp (2,1) instead.

Answer (score 0):

That is very odd. Your code, to me, reads logically and syntactically correct. I would agree with you on where the problem is. Short of me debugging it myself, I would suggest you try the simple numbers for the program (n=1, m=1 ; n=4, m=1 ; n=2, m=1 ; n=2, m=0). If that's all fine then it very well seems to be that the problem lies exactly where you've pointed out.

I know that doesn't solve your problem but it's a start (if you haven't done it already). I would, because I'm insane, also try

```
else {
  power = power-1;
  base = base * exp(base, power);
}
```

I'm not sure if that'll help (it'll definitely be slower), but perhaps worth the try? I would also remove a lot of the references.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have a C-Plus-Plus program/compiler on here. Stupid macbooks. (just kidding, I love them)

Comment: yeah, I know the problem is there. but I don't get the logic why it's wrong. I could write the codes like `else {pwr /= 2; base = exp(base, pwr) * exp(base, pwr);}` and get the right answer. but i am trying to figure out what's wrong with this expresssion.

Comment: Then use various numebrs and compute it yourself. You'll find out easily, haha. Old paper and pen does the trick...

Comment: @victoroux g++ is included with every Apple computer. You can run files from Terminal using `g++ FILENAME` then seeing the output with `./a.out`

Comment: @victoroux you know you can download dev tools for free for any mac, right? If you're running Lion, just download XCode 4 from the app store, else download XCode 3 from apple.com.

Comment: @Chris it does require an additional install, unfortunately. If he still has the OS X install disks, he can get whatever version of the dev tools came with his copy.